# C++ iterator to last element of a linked list?

Tags: c++, list, iterator, listiterator

I'd like to get the `::iterator` to the last element of the `list`.

My understanding is that you can get the iterator to the `.front()` of the list with `.begin()`, but what about the `.back()`?  As the list boundaries are not inclusive of the final element, `.end()` would be the iterator past the `back()` element of the list.

I've tried using `.rbegin()`, as logically that appears to be just what I want, but it appears to return a `reverse_iterator` type, which results in a mismatched type for my code.

Comment: what is your code? `rbegin()` is the correct function to use, why can't your code work with a `reverse_iterator`?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, because it's of type `iterator`, not a `reverse_iterator`, and they don't seem to map

Comment: But why does your code have to use an `iterator`? This is what templated code is for

Comment: @AlanBirtles how else do I save a pointer to an element of the `std::list` linked list in an `std::map`, if not for using a `list<…>::iterator`?  This is for a C++ implementation of an LRU cache, and, as per related question, my approach already resulted in the best-case runtime!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51236501/1122270

Comment: well if it said that in your question... post an [mcve], get correct answers

Comment: @AlanBirtles why?  I already know what I want, and others easily saw that as well without even any clarifications from my side necessary.  You still haven't answered what I'm doing wrong, and I trust you, too, should have the complete picture of my objective now as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm is the same for any bidirectional container:

```
#include <list>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>


template<typename Container>
auto iter_to_last(Container&& cont)
{
    auto last = std::end(cont);
    if (last == std::begin(cont))
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("container is empty");
    }
    return std::prev(last);
}

int main()
{
    auto l = std::list<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << *iter_to_last(l) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *iter_to_last(std::set<int> { 1, 2, 3 }) << std::endl;
    std::cout << *iter_to_last(std::vector<int> { 1, 2, 3 }) << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
3
3
3
```

Answer (score 3):

If the list supports bidirectional iterator, use

```
auto last = list.empty() ? list.end() : std::prev(list.end());
```

For a one-way list like **forward_list** traversing the list from the beginning is the only option (at least as far as I know):

```
auto last = list.end();
for (auto it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); last = it++);
```

**last** points either to the last element or to list.end() if the list is empty.

Comment: Caution: the behavior of a program that uses this code on an empty list is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a condition check.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible answer (for a non-empty list) is `--l.end()`.

Provided the `std::list` isn't empty, it appears that the following options for the last element are then available:

- `--l.end()`
- `prev(l.end())`

Note that `&(l.back())` doesn't appear to work, as it doesn't result in an iterator.