# C++: can I reuse / move an std::list element from middle to end?

Tags: c++, memory, iterator, micro-optimization, stdlist

I'm optimising constant factors of my LRU-cache implementation, where I use `std::unordered_map` to store `::iterator`s to `std::list`, which are guaranteed to remain valid even as nearby elements are added or removed.  This results in O(n) runtime, so, I'm going after the constant factors.

I understand that each iterator is basically a pointer to the structure that holds my stuff.  Currently, to move a given element to the back of the linked list, I call `l.erase(it)` with the iterator, and then allocate a new pair w/ `make_pair(key, value)` to `l.push_back()` or `l.emplace_back()` (not too sure of the difference), and get the new iterator back for insertion into the map w/ [`prev(l.end())` or `--l.end()`](//stackoverflow.com/a/51235853/1122270).

Is there a way to re-use an existing iterator and the underlying doubly-linked list structure that it points to, instead of having to destroy it each time as per above?

(My runtime is currently 56ms (beats 99.78%), but the best C++ submission on leetcode is 50ms.)

Comment: [`std::list::splice()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice)?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear based on your description what exactly is the key and the value of the unordered map, and how it relates to the list. Rather than paragraphasing, a [mcve], containing your sample operations you wish to optimize, would be more enlightening.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, yes, seems to work!  and so much easier, too!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, do you wanna answer it, or should I answer this Q myself?

Comment: sadly, splice doesn't actually result in a faster runtime, though.

Comment: I'm ok with you answering.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks, done!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, this question is basically all about the list by itself; the map simply provides a background of what I'm attempting to do; anyhow, the comment prior to yours was exactly on point; also, I did provide the exact example of what I'm trying to reduce — see the code snippets that are provided — those are the things I was trying to get rid of; done successfully with std::list::splice().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by [HolyBlackCat](//stackoverflow.com/users/2752075/holyblackcat), the solution is to use `std::list::splice`.

```
l.splice(l.end(), l, it);
```

This avoid any need to `l.erase`, `make_pair()`, `l.push_back` / `l.emplace_back()`, as well getting the `prev(l.end())` / `--l.end()` to update the underlying `std::map`.

<del>Sadly, though, it doesn't result in a better runtime speed, but, oh well, possibly a measurement variation, then, or an implementation using more specialised data structures.</del>

Update: actually, I fixed the final instance of reusing the "removed" elements from `l.begin()`, and got 52ms / 100%! :-)

Comment: Ok, it's pretty funny, because it's like a pretty old problem on LeetCode, yet since my submission two days ago, someone got a runtime of 40ms, whereas mine is 52ms (beats 99,96% — was 100% two days ago).  Did they simply cache the answer based on input in their solution, or is it a legit optimisation somehow?!

Comment: Actually, LeetCode lets you see solutions once you solve it, and it looks like the 40ms solution is using a `vector` in place of `list`, with its own head and tail pointers to part of this vector, plus a few other tricks.}  Funny how it must have been the SO that got someone to submit such a solution. :)